# SQL Query Union

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join two tables and pull multiple records from the right table and combine them into one line. I made a SQL Fiddle for it. I'm not positive my approach is correct, but it's the closest I've got. Ideally the query should show two lines for:
Posey - A - 1 and 
Curry - C - 1.
Kaep should be out cause he has the 0.

Thanks for looking. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8739a/7/0)

Here are the relevant details described:

2 tables for a person and a registration. The registration has rows for each of the person's selections when registering (i.e. registration type and a yes/no answer). Both regtype and yesno entries have toggles to let me know when that record is being stored. I want to know the Person's details combined with their RegistrationType and if they selected Yes for the YesNoEntry.

Here is the table structure and some dummy inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE RegPerson (
  RegPersonID INT,
  FirstName VARCHAR(32),
  LastName VARCHAR(32),
  Company VARCHAR(32),
  Dummy1 INT
);

CREATE TABLE Reg (
  RegID INT,
  RegPersonID INT,
  RegItemID INT,
  RefNumber INT,
  RegistrationToggle BINARY,
  RegistrationType VARCHAR(32),
  YesNoToggle BINARY,
  YesNoEntry BINARY,
  Dummy2 VARCHAR(32),
  Dummy3 BINARY
);

INSERT INTO RegPerson
          SELECT 1, 'Buster', 'Posey', 'Giants', 456
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Colin', 'Kaepernick', '49ers', 765
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Stephen', 'Curry', 'Warriors', 321;

INSERT INTO Reg
          SELECT 1, 1, 1, 98765, 0, '', 0, 0, 'asdf', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 2, 98765, 1, 'A', 0, 0, 'qwer', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 3, 98765, 0, '', 1, 1, 'rtyu', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 1, 12345, 0, '', 0, 0, 'jkl;', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2, 2, 12345, 1, 'B', 0, 0, 'cvnb', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 3, 12345, 0, '', 1, 0, 'zxcv', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 3, 1, 56789, 0, '', 0, 0, 'poiu', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 3, 2, 56789, 1, 'C', 0, 0, 'cvnb', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 3, 3, 56789, 0, '', 1, 1, 'zxcv', 0;
```

Comment: Please add all relevant info into the question. If SQLFIddle is not available your question is useless.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Just updated with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gives you the rows you want:

```
select a.refnumber,
       c.firstname,
       c.lastname,
       c.company,
       a.registrationtype,
       b.yesnoentry
from reg a, reg b, regperson c
  where a.refnumber=b.refnumber
  and a.regpersonid=c.regpersonid
  and a.registrationtype !=''
  and b.yesnotoggle=1
  and b.yesnoentry=1;
```

Since you're storing multiple parts of the data in the reg table, you have to self join to view the entire record. You could restructure your data to use just one row, or create a separate table to store the yes or no values. Though as long as your data set isn't huge, this will work just fine.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I can't store it all on the same row because the row count is dynamic. Admin creates a form that's stored in a different table and these are the entries into the form. This is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know you could self join, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Checking your SQLFiddle example, I think that you don't need `UNION` but a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    Reg.RefNumber, 
    RegPerson.FirstName, 
    RegPerson.LastName, 
    RegPerson.Company, 
    Reg.RegistrationType, 
    Reg.YesNoEntry
FROM 
    Reg
    INNER JOIN RegPerson ON RegPerson.RegPersonID = Reg.RegPersonID
WHERE 
    Reg.RegItemID = 3
    Reg.YesNoToggle = 1
    AND Reg.YesNoEntry = 1
```

This query will get the data of the persons that have a record in *both* tables. As I understand it, a person can have a record in `reg` *only if* it has a record in `regPerson` already.

If you want to deduplicate the list and show only the names, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    RegPerson.FirstName, 
    RegPerson.LastName, 
    RegPerson.Company, 
FROM 
    Reg
    INNER JOIN RegPerson ON RegPerson.RegPersonID = Reg.RegPersonID
WHERE 
    Reg.RegItemID = 3
    Reg.YesNoToggle = 1
    AND Reg.YesNoEntry = 1
```

Hope this helps.